# One monitor shows static noise when I play the video (John Denver - Country Roads) on YouTube

Tags: firefox, video, multiple-monitors, youtube

One of my monitors are showing static noise whenever I listen to *John Denver - Take Me Home, Country Roads* on YouTube. I understand that it must sound like some kind of joke. I can't even begin to understand why that would be happening. I have reinstalled Firefox and have checked the monitors cable pins and switched the cables.

If there are anyone who would have a technical suggestion on why this is happening, please let me know.

[Here is a video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CdDYPaVepU) that showcases the issue.

**To replicate error: (For me)**

1. Open Firefox
2. Go to YouTube.com
3. Search for [John Denver - Take Me Home, Country Roads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vrEljMfXYo), [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vrEljMfXYo)
4. Play video
5. Primary monitor starts to display static noise

Note: 1 Pixel on the top of the monitor screen remains visible. (Shown in the YouTube video.)

Comment: Does it happen in a different browser?  Does it happen if you play the video in the affected monitor?  What if you physically move the affected monitor away from the other monitor and/or speakers?  What happens of you swap the ports the monitors are connected to?   What if you swap ports and repeat the above steps?  Add the results to your question.

Comment: It doesn't happen in a different browser. Playing the video in the affected monitor results in the same issue. Moving the monitor didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing history and cache solved the issue. I've done some testing, but can't be certain that this is a permanent solution.